# Simple rocket model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

I have a problem creating a model for a horizontal rocket flight.

I want to model a rocket with constant force, drag constant and gravity. I also have to account for a changing mass and drag. I know I could calculate movement of this rocket by something like Runge-Kutta algorithm but I want to know if it is possible to create a equation that would give me a position (height) for a given time.

Basically those are my functions:

$$F_G (t) = - g \, m (t)$$

$$F_D (t) = - c \, v^2 (t)$$

$$F (t) = F_T (t) - F_G (t) + F_D (t)$$

where $F_T$ is the (constant) thrust, $F_G$ is gravity, and $F_D$ is drag.

I'm kinda stuck here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i suppose at some point you have to write down something like Newton's second law, which is a 2nd order ODE, and then solve it for the trajectory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you rocket is still not fast enough. By Newton's second law (like gt6989 said):

$m\ddot{x}+\dot{m}\dot{x}=F(t)-gm-c\dot{x}^2$ or $$m\ddot{x}+\dot{m}\dot{x}+c\dot{x}^2=F(t)-gm$$
You still need to give models for the thrust and also for the mass which is lost. An explicit solution will not be that easy.

You could also introduce the substitution $\dot{x}=z$

$$m\dot{z}+\dot{m}z+cz^2=F(t)-gm$$

This is a riccati differnetial equation. You might be lucky if there is a general explicit solution.

$$\dot{z}=\frac{m_d}{m}z-\frac{c}{m}z^2+\frac{F(t)}{m}-g$$

$$\dot{z}=\frac{m_d}{m_0 - m_d t}z-\frac{c}{m_0 - m_d t}z^2+\frac{F_0}{m_0 - m_d t}-g$$

Maple gives an explicit solution with Bessel functions. [image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
F(t) is constant and m(t) = m0 - md * t. Can you give me any tips on how I should approach solving this equation?

Comment: This is not quite right: Newton's second law is $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ not truly $F=ma$. So the change in mass appears both in the change in the gravity *and* in a term unto itself. Specifically (under these assumptions about the thrust etc.) you should have $m\ddot{x}-m_d \dot{x}+c\dot{x}^2=F_0-g(m-m_d t)$. (Also, neat, now I see an alternate way to physically explain the meaning of "negative linear drag").

Comment: @Ian: Thank you totally missed to that.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. Just one thing, shouldnt all m-s be m0-md*t? And if so doesn't it complicate things since it is coefficient of x'?

Comment: @simch: Sorry, I did a little mistake. Please have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: So if there is no explicit soulution i should solve it numerically(Euler or better Runge-Kutta)?

Comment: I am not an expert in numerical methods. But I would try to use Runge-Kutta because of higher accuracy.

Comment: Added the "explicit" solution using Bessel functions. given some initial data this soultion might simplify a little bit.